# HTTP Client in DoFn

Tags: http, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I would like to make POST request through a DoFn for a Apache Beam Pipeline running on Dataflow.

For that, I have created a client which instanciate an HttpClosableClient configured on a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.

However, I instanciate a client for each element that I process.

How could I setup a persistent client used by all my elements?

And is there other class for parallel and high-speed HTTP requests that I should use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the client into a member variable, use the `@Setup` method to open it, and `@Teardown` to close it. Implementation of almost all IOs in Beam uses this pattern, e.g. see [JdbcIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java).

Comment: I believe the equivalent for python is start_bundle and finish_bundle. See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.3.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.start_bundle